# Finding match element with array reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have two arrays

```
a. [1,2,3,4,5]

b. [2,3,4,5,6]
```

I try to find 2,3,4,5 with `array.reduce` because I think it is **more efficient**.

Can I do so?

Comment: if you have only two array then you can just `filter` it out. Maybe something like this: `a.filter(p=>b.includes(p))`

Comment: If your arrays are that small, there should be no concern about efficiency. If however you have thousands of values, then use a `Set`.

Comment: If I really want to use reduce is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the same result without using `reduce`:

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];
var b= [2,3,4,5,6];

result = a.filter(p=>b.includes(p));

console.log(result);
```

Or with reduce:

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];
var b= [2,3,4,5,6];

var result = b.reduce((acc,elem)=>{
    if(a.includes(elem)) acc.push(elem);
    return acc; 
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
{
  const a = [1,2,3,4,5];

  const b = [2,3,4,5,6];
  
  let overlap = a.filter(e => b.includes(e))
  console.log(overlap)
}
```